# rounding double to currency string outputs for crypto currencies

Tags: c#, floating-point, tostring

### current situation and issue

I currently have an issue to display the available amount of a crypto currency in my wallet in a meaningful way.
the issue is that the usd equivalents of the cryptos are differing immensly and thus the required precisions are varying a lot.

For instance, lets say I have 50 USD worth in any given cryptocurrency of my wallet. At the time of writing, this would look like the following:

| currency | shib | usdt | btc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| amount (50 usd each) | 6273525.72145... | 50 | 0.0023707‬ |

in a real world example, it looks like the following:
[image]

### existing solution (for classic currencies)

Lets say I go for a classic formatting of currencies:

```
currency.ToString("0.##");
```

| currency | shib | usdt | btc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| amount | 6273525.72 | 50.00 | 0.00 |

while this would work great for currencies such as shib or usdt, currencies with higher value such as btc or eth will have problems with this:
[image]

### pseudo-code/solution

I think it would be feasible to go with 3 digits of precision for the first significant digit after the comma:

```
if (amount >= 1)
{ // in a range to show 2 decimals
    string result = amount.ToString("0.##"); // eg 5.93
}
else
{ // truncate to precision of 3
    // 0.0184432468325 -> "0.0184"
    // 0.00237392482309 -> "0.00237"
    // 0.00043930984274 -> "0.000439"
    // 0.00000000001279 -> "0.0000000000127"
    // 0.123000004234 -> "0.123"
}
```

how would I go about the last part (if amount is smaller 0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure this is a good approach or not, you may look for regex.

[Regex 101 with Sample Test Data](https://regex101.com/r/z5yDMk/1)

```
^(0.0*\d{1,3})
```

The above regex captures the group amount with a pattern starting with "0.", has zero or more "0" and lastly any numeric characters with at least 1 and up to 3 occurrences.

```cs
public static string TruncateSmallerZeroCryptoAmt(double amount)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("^(0.0*\\d{3})");
    var match = regex.Match(String.Format("{0:F20}", amount));
        
    return match.Value.TrimEnd('0');
}
```

The reason why is to convert `double` to `string` with a formatting pattern so that the output string will not have E (exponential).

While `.TrimEnd('0')` is to remove the extra zeros at the back due to previous formatting.

For example:

> 0.300 --> Display as 0.3

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BY5HdZ)

Comment: oh, that works well!